# Mac OSX: NKE iff_event_func on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks, kernel-extension

I implemented an `iff_event_func` callback specifically to detect `KEV_DL_IF_DETACHING` and `KEV_DL_IF_DETACHED` events.

On 10.8.5, I see that my function is called when I surprise-remove an interface, such as a USB-tethered phone. However, the event_code member of the `kev_msg` data has a value of 13 (`KEV_DL_LINK_ON`) instead of 10 (`KEV_DL_IF_DETACHING`).

I verified that the `iff_event_func` callback with `event_code == 13` is made before the call to my `iff_detached_func` function, so the `iff_event_func` call appears to notifying my `NKE` about an upcoming detachment. However, I can't see why I'm getting `KEV_DL_LINK_ON` instead of `KEV_DL_IF_DETACHING`.

I saw in [this changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/Kernel.html) that `KEV_DL_IF_DETACHING` (along with many of the `KEV_DL_IF_xxx` values) were apparently added for 10.9. So, that implies that 10.8.5 does not support `KEV_DL_IF_DETACHING`.

My questions are:

1. If KEV_DL_IF_DETACHING is not supported on 10.8.5, what KEV_DL_xxx event should I use to handle a  notification of a filter detachment?
2. If many of these KEV_DL_IF_xxx values are not supported on 10.8.5, is there any benefit to specifying an iff_event_func callback in the iff_filter struct for 10.8.5?
3. Is there an API that a kext can call to determine the version of the OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with OSX 10.8.5 and 10.9.1, and is being tracked by problem 16342178.